# How to compare old road bikes

Tags: road-bike, used-bike

I'm looking for a retro road bike and found a Gudereit T30 with a steel frame, 12 gears, and Mavic rims.

How can I compare this bike to more common bikes to figure out its value?

Comparing the shifters and gears seems easy (DuraAce-Ultegra-105), but how do I compare the steel frame and wheels?

Some pictures:

http://cl.ly/image/1g1h2G0c2d2O

http://cl.ly/image/2b2m2G2l0J0w

Comment: another picture: http://cl.ly/image/3J0A00171L0h

Comment: This is a shopping question and is likely to be closed since it doesn't really help the SE format.

Comment: Yeah, might be better if you ask how to determine prices in general, based on age of the bike, and the original selling prices, and what other factors can affect the price of the bike. Look for similar bikes in classifieds (online and print) in your area, to determine what other people are asking.  The price one can get for a bike often depends on how much biking happens in your area, as this affects supply and demand.

Comment: I changed the question to fit more to the SE format.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable estimate can be found using a site like [Bicycle Blue Book](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/). This site is a database of used bike sale transactions going back for almost a decade, and has a number of pretty obscure manufacturers listed. You can even add upgrades you have made from the stock and get an estimate of how that changes the value, though it doesn't account for things like racks, fenders and lighting systems you would add to a bike to make it a competent commuter bike.

I've sold 4 bikes within the last 6 months, and all 4 sold within a reasonable range of what was listed on that site.

Answer (score 1):

The bicycle blue book does not include a Gudereit, which is a German brand. It seems to miss information about a lot of European brands and models yet.

Sometimes a sticker on the frame indicates the build quality. There is a sticker just below the saddle and on diagonal tube almost entirely at the front if I see it correctly. If one of those says something about the type of steel used, this is a great indicator for the build quality.

Besides this, you can only compare it to similar brands with similar parts in your region.

Comment: the sticker on the frame: http://cl.ly/image/3P293p2p1N1x
Raynolds Steel

Comment: Raynolds steel is exactly what you want with an old frame like this. 453 is not the highest grade, but this is not a problem at all. This was a mid-range/upper-range bicycle with good parts. If you really wan't a price estimate, you can compare it to other bicycles with a Reynolds frame and the same Shimano parts. Don't compare it to the very top brands of racing-bicycles (Miyata, Pinarello, Colnage, etc.) but compare it to well known general brands (Peugeot, Giant, etc.). This should give you an idea.